# Is $(f_k)$ a Cauchy sequence on $C^0_∞[−1, 1]$ under the Supremum Norm?

Tags: functional-analysis, cauchy-sequences

I’m trying to show that the following sequence of functions is or is not a Cauchy sequence on $C^0[-1,1]$ space under $\|.\|_{\infty}$ but I cannot obtain something concrete.

Consider the sequence of functions $(f_k)$ where each $f_k : [−1, 1] → \mathbb R$ is defined by:

$$f_k(x) =
\begin{cases}
-1,  & \text{if $-1\le x\le -1/k$} \\
kx, & \text{if $-1/k\le x\le 1/k$} \\
1, & \text{if $1/k\le x\le 1$}
\end{cases}$$

Is $(f_k)$ a Cauchy sequence on $C^0_∞[−1, 1]$?

Should I use the negation of the Cauchy Sequence definition?

Comment: If $(f_k) converges under the sup norm then  the limit function is continuous? Do you know what the pointwise lmit is ?

Comment: $f_k(1/(2k))=1/2$ while $f_{2k}(1/(2k))=1.$ So it is not  Cauchy sequence in $C^0[-1,1].$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc I can't see how. could you explain me?

Comment: By definition the Cauchy sequence of functions should satsify $\sup_{0\le x\le 1} |f_n(x)-f_m(x)| to 0$ when $n,m\to \infty.$ In other words the graphs of $f_n$ and $f_m$ are close to each other when $n,m$ are large.  For example we may require that the graphs of $f_n$ should be close to each other less than $1/3.$ for large indices. But the distance of the graps $f_k$ and $f_{2k}$ is greater or equal $1/2$ no matter how large $k$ is. This contradicts the Cauchy condition.

Comment: Thanks, i was trying another way and it was getting complicated. It only remains to formalize it.